# What is the physical representation of a qubit?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture

In regular computers, bits may be physically represented using a wide variety of two-state devices, such as polarity of magnetization of a certain area of a ferromagnetic film or two levels of electric charge in a capacitor.

But qubits have a property that they can be in a superposition of both states at the same time. I've seen [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1182/)'s answers, which explain how can a qubit be represented, or modeled using a regular computer.

So I want to know what can be used (and is used by companies like D-Wave) to represent a qubit in a real physical quantum computer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Developments) on Wikipedia collects the most important ongoing attempts to physically implement qubits.

> For physically implementing a quantum computer, many different
>   candidates are being pursued, among them (distinguished by the
>   physical system used to realize the qubits):
>
> - Superconducting quantum computing (qubit implemented by the state of small superconducting circuits (Josephson junctions))
> - Trapped ion quantum computer (qubit implemented by the internal state of trapped ions)
> - Optical lattices (qubit implemented by internal states of neutral atoms trapped in an optical lattice)
> - Quantum dot computer, spin-based (e.g. the Loss-DiVincenzo quantum computer) (qubit given by the spin states of trapped electrons)
> - Quantum dot computer, spatial-based (qubit given by electron position in double quantum dot)
> - Nuclear magnetic resonance on molecules in solution (liquid-state NMR) (qubit provided by nuclear spins within the dissolved molecule)
> - Solid-state NMR Kane quantum computers (qubit realized by the nuclear spin state of phosphorus donors in silicon)
> - Electrons-on-helium quantum computers (qubit is the electron spin)
> - Cavity quantum electrodynamics (CQED) (qubit provided by the internal state of  trapped atoms coupled to high-finesse cavities)
> - Molecular magnet (qubit given by spin states)
> - Fullerene-based ESR quantum computer (qubit based on the electronic spin of atoms or molecules encased in fullerenes)
> - Linear optical quantum computer (qubits realized by processing states of different modes of light through linear elements e.g.
>     mirrors, beam splitters and phase shifters)
> - Diamond-based quantum computer (qubit realized by electronic or nuclear spin of nitrogen-vacancy centers in diamond)
> - Bose–Einstein condensate-based quantum computer
> - Transistor-based quantum computer – string quantum computers with entrainment of positive holes using an electrostatic trap
> - Rare-earth-metal-ion-doped inorganic crystal based quantum computers (qubit realized by the internal electronic state of dopants in optical
>     fibers)
> - Metallic-like carbon nanospheres based quantum computers
>
> The large number of candidates demonstrates that the topic, in spite
>   of rapid progress, is still in its infancy. There is also a vast
>   amount of flexibility.