# How many types of quantum computers are currently being researched?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization, architecture

I came across a "new" type of quantum computer - photonic quantum computing. Is this type of technology of interest here? You may read about an example [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/an-interactive-tutorial-on-quantum-programming-327da388f859). I wonder how many types of quantum computers are now researched? Any good summary of these technologies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the physical representation of a qubit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1395)

Comment: Photonic quantum computing is nothing new. The research has been ongoing for decades. (It's the second most promising physical realization after superconducting quantum computing.)

Comment: The other question/response was perfect. Thanks. Are all these "Qubits" with the same behavior? Same superstition features and other quantum-mechanics model(s)?

Comment: You're welcome. All qubits respect a  two dimensional complex Hilbert space structure, so each one can demonstrate quantum superposition. The other physical properties of different types of qubits certainly differ - the textbook by Nielsen and Chuang has a nice introduction to different types of such physical implementations; I'd suggest reading that for a start.

Comment: Actually the claim for Photonic Quantum Computing is that "the CV model uses qumodes that reside in an infinite dimensional space" and "quantum operations in CV quantum computers operate in an infinite dimensional space called the Hilbert space"

Comment: Actually it seems more like a 3D complex Hilbert space.

Comment: The continuous variable model is for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces, yes.