# What are the general hardware components of a universal quantum gate computer?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture

Although the architecture of a quantum computer depends on the implemented qubit system, I still wonder what the general structure of hardware parts would be.

Evidently, a quantum computer isn't merely comprised of qubits, so probably multiple devices must be required to realize the existence of a physical quantum computer. Which devices would that be and what is the pertaining purpose of each component.

In case certain helpful sources are available for finding such data, I would gladly like to receive a reference then. A schematic or primitive blueprint would also be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/what-is-the-physical-representation-of-a-qubit?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Nonetheless, technically it is not a duplicate since I am not specifically interested in the physical implementation of Qubits. My question focuses on which parts a quantum computer requires, besides the actual Qubits, and I haven't quite found a decent 'blueprint' so far. Therefore I hoped one could perhaps provide an answer or appreciate source.

Comment: this totally depends on the implementation. Superconducting quantum computers will have completely different components than say ion trap ones. Even fixing a single type of architecture many components will probably be implemented differently in different research groups. This question should essentially be asked separately for each entry in the list in the linked question

Comment: from a very general point of view, other than the information carriers themselves (the qubits or variation thereof), you need something to control their evolution/make them interact (to decide which gates to implement in the circuit model) and something to measure them. But even this distinction doesn't really work for things like one-way quantum computation.