# How the various quantum gates are implemented physically in quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-gate, resource-request

I'm not able to find any sources. Can you point me to some?

Comment: Welcome on the QC SE! I think yes, there are a lot of sources, although most of them is hard. If the community finds your question too broad ("needs more focus"), I suggest to read some of them, and then ask the details of a specific implementation (like by photon spins or so). What you learn in this process, will help you to ask this time much more liked (=upvoted) questions.

Comment: *Quantum computation and quantum information* from Nielsen and Chuang + *Quantum computing for computer scientist* from Yanofsky and Noson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the physical representation of a qubit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/what-is-the-physical-representation-of-a-qubit)

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting article that talks about creating a Fredkin quantum gate (controlled SWAP) : https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/3/e1501531

I hope this can help you in your search.

Answer (score 1):

[This playlist by QuTech Academy](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ) on the 'building blocks' of a quantum computer might offer some nice insights.

- Video $10$ & $11$ introduce spin qubits, with [the second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBnKec6uI0U&list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ&index=11) specifically on the **operations on spin qubits**.
- Video $12$ & $13$ introduce NV centre qubits, with [again the second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWd0SkoI0HY&list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ&index=13) specifically on the **operations on spin qubits**.
- Video $14$ through $19$ introduce the widely used **transmon qubits**, with [measurements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDANvtOkEc4&list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ&index=17), [single-qubit operations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MfABBLtBd0&list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ&index=18) and the [two-qubit operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwjlEdwi2LU&list=PL5jmbd6SJYnPiYlM6pHAm2M3FL40D9otZ&index=19) in separate videos.
- Video $20$ through $25$ introduce the concepts behind a majorana-based topological quantum computer, but so far there's little 'physical' about that (unfortunately)

Notable omissions include (as QuTech doesn't work on these technologies):

- Trapped ion systems. Check for instance [this video by MIT Opencourseware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJOuPmI--5c) for the basics.
- Photon-based systems, most notably the [linear KLM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLM_protocol). Check the (wiki)link for the introduction on how the gates are implemented (hint: beam splitters and mirrors).

Of course there's also adiabatic-style quantum computers, but there you don't perform 'gates', you just tune the coupling between qubit neighbour pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information about gates implementation here in this article:

[Realization of efficient quantum gates with a superconducting qubit-qutrit circuit](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-49657-1)

Although the proposed setup is rather experimental, it may give you some ideas how to implement gates on computers with superconducting qubits.