# Can quantum computers design quantum computers autonomously better than other methods?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture, quantum-turing-machine

We've seen people use computers to design computers, AI to write computer programs, robots teach themselves, and even robots build themselves. I understand that conventional computers can be used to emulate quantum computers.

[image: Emika Robotic Arm builds it's co-workers.]

**Robotic arm builds more robotic arms.**

---

**My question is:** Will quantum computers be **inherently able** to design **better** quantum computers (which presumably robots could then build) or is that task better suited to Deep Learning / AI and conventional computers (with human intervention)?

Perhaps another way to ask the question, though I'm fairly certain that this won't make it clearer: "Do conventional computers limit us to quantum  Darwinism while quantum computers might enable universal Darwinism **with respect to** the evolution of quantum computer design?".

Oversimplified (**not** ***the*** **question**): Could they understand (design) themselves better than classical computers, Deep Learning / AI, or mankind - IE: they do not suffer from what Zurek calls “pointer states”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Sort of, quite possibly, if by degrees

*This is a speculative, but plausible, answer*

First of all, **how do qubits interact and states evolve with time?**

The description of how individual qubits evolve (i.e. a single qubit gate operation) is given by some Hamiltonian<sup>1</sup>. Multiple, non-interacting qubits (that are exactly the same) therefore evolve using multiples of that same Hamiltonian. However, as soon as you include some form of interaction, simulating the exact evolution of a large number of interacting qubits quickly becomes intractable (which is exactly why quantum computers should be useful, in theory).

Now, **how are quantum processors *designed?***

Designing the microarchitecture of a processor (such as the connectivity, layout of the chip etc.) is one thing, but engineering sizes of qubits, waveguides etc. requires going on a computer and running detailed simulations a lot of the time. If there was a way to simulate large Hamiltonians for a long time, it's reasonable to assume that this would help improve knowledge of how the qubits interact with each other and the environment, such as in a more detailed version of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2377v1) and extensions thereof, as well as generally being able to look at how multiple qubits interact at once. This would in turn allow for improved design of the *details* of chip, which would lead to effects such as reduction of decoherence.

Finally, **what are quantum computers good at?**

As mentioned above, quantum computers are potentially useful because of what makes them hard to simulate - a quantum computer *is* a system that quickly becomes intractable it simulate with increasing numbers of qubits. However, something that quantum computers offer a speedup of is... [*Hamiltonian simulation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1318v3).

In other words, by iteratively running a quantum Hamiltonian simulation, using a classical computer to (tell the quantum computer to) vary certain parameters, it's not unreasonable to assume that a quantum computer could help for optimising certain aspects of the chip to e.g. reduce decoherence times, improve fidelities etc. In turn offering *better* simulations and allowing for yet more qubits, which potentially offers better simulations and the continual improvement would (hopefully) begin.

As for whether it *does*, or if classically simulating a few qubits and extrapolating from this would give a just-as-good design is something that only time will tell.

---

<sup>1 Having said that, in linear optical quantum computers (at least), unitaries are implemented *directly* using physical components such as beam splitters and phase shifters directly describing the unitary, as opposed to, say, superconducting, where applying microwaves is described in terms of a Hamiltonian, which is then used to *give* a unitary. OK, all this is maybe simplifying a bit, but that gets the gist across. What *does* matter is that, in linear optical quantum computers, *generating* the photons on say, a ring resonator, is described by a Hamiltonian</sup>

Answer (score 4):

We don't yet know if quantum computers are actually better than classical computers, as @heather mentions [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/168/26). As for now there are just some theoretical algorithms which we know of, specifically for quantum-computers, which have much better time complexities than equivalent classical algorithms. For example - [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) and [discrete logarithms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/365700/).

Wiki also says:

> Besides factorization and discrete logarithms, quantum algorithms
>   offering a more than polynomial speedup over the best known classical
>   algorithm have been found for several problems, including the
>   simulation of quantum physical processes from chemistry and solid
>   state physics, the approximation of Jones polynomials, and solving
>   Pell's equation. No mathematical proof has been found that shows that
>   an equally fast classical algorithm cannot be discovered, although
>   this is considered unlikely. For some problems, quantum computers
>   offer a polynomial speedup. The most well-known example of this is
>   quantum database search, which can be solved by Grover's algorithm
>   using quadratically fewer queries to the database than are required by
>   classical algorithms. In this case the advantage is provable. Several
>   other examples of provable quantum speedups for query problems have
>   subsequently been discovered, such as for finding collisions in
>   two-to-one functions and evaluating NAND trees.

Whether you can use these speedups to *design* better quantum computers, depends. I can imagine that you could of course simulate a quantum computer using another quantum computer, which could help in making new designs or rather testing-before-building. But I don't think polynomial speedups, faster prime factorizations, etc. will directly help in designing a quantum computer, unless you actually make use of it somehow.

---

P.S: This is a very short and perhaps incomplete answer, I know. I just wanted to give the OP a basic idea. I'd request others to write alternate answers to this question.