# Is there any source which tabulates quantum computing algorithms for simulating physical systems?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, resource-request

I was wondering if there is a source (online or review article) which tabulates recent algorithms, and their complexities, used in simulating various physical systems. Something along the lines of:

**Physical System 1**: Quantum Field Theory (scattering)

**Complexity**: Polynomial in number of particles, energy, and precision

**Source**: [Quantum Algorithms for Quantum Field Theories (Jordan, Lee & Preskill, 2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3633)

**Physical System 2**: Atomic Energy levels

And so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there emulators for quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-there-emulators-for-quantum-computers)

Comment: Are you particularly interested in _simulation_ or _emulation_? You may wish to clarify this.

Comment: @Discretelizard According to the question, the OP (welcome to quantum computing SE by the way!) is looking for a quantum algorithm for simulating a physical system, which isn't the same as looking for something that can emulate a qc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you're after is [NIST's Quantum Zoo](https://math.nist.gov/quantum/zoo/), a comprehensive catalog of quantum algorithms maintained by Stephen Jordan. Its sections include:

- Algebraic and Number Theoretic Algorithms (14 items)
- Oracular Algorithms (34 items)
- Approximation and Simulation Algorithms (12 items)

and for each algorithm it includes its speedup, a description and relevant references. The third category would be the answer to the present question.

Comment: Thanks this resource looks great.  What I was interested is under the first sub-section of the "Approximation and Simulation Algorithms".